# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::view()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I have Laravel installed and now I keep getting this error everytime I run `composer update`, `php artisan routes`, or any composer commands:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Response::view()
```

I already searched the internet and tried the following suggested solutions so far and nothing worked:

1) A lot of suggested answer on the net says to delete `vendor/compiled.php` and run the composer update again. But when I went to vendor folder, I cannot find any compiled.php file there. The only file that exists there is: autoload.php

2) I also tried searching for compiled.php inside `storage/framework/` folder and nothing there neither.

3) I even tried running optimize with the --force flag `php artisan optimize --force` and it shows the same error as above.

4) I looked at boostrap/autoload.php for compiled path and it says `$compiledPath = __DIR__.'/cache/compiled.php';` I can only see the boostrap/cache folder and that doesnt have this file.

What is wrong here? I am new to Laravel and I dont understand what this error means. Going by the answers out there, I am going around looking for `compiled.php` to delete and run the update again and I dont even know if that is the right solution for it. Can someone help me here please on how do I proceed troubleshooting this?

I have **Laravel 5.1.6** installed after the update I did yesterday. I also ran the `composer dumpautoload` command today and I wonder if this error started happening after that. Now any commands in composer is giving the above error.

**EDIT:**
Now even my browser view of the site is showing the error:

```
FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 210: 
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::missing()
```

I also tried deleting the complete vendor folder and composer.lock, and re-ran `composer install`. Towards the end of the installation when generating autoload files, it showed this error again and stopped.

**EDIT 2:**
@NehalHasnayeen in the comments got it absolutely right. This error was caused due to app calling the view method on Response class, while the response class had no view method. Once I removed that from my route, it worked. This is my route file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
    //return View::make('index');
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});

// -------- THIS WAS CAUSING THE ISSUE - REMOVING THIS WORKED AFTER THAT ------
//App::missing(function($exception) {
//    return view('index');
//});
```

It takes me to my final question, why was the catch-all route throwing this error? I read from [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-laravel-and-angular-single-page-comment-application) that adding the above will redirect all other route requests to index. What is the right method? Did it change in Laravel 5 or have I done something wrong?

Comment: You performed an upgrade to 5.1.6, right? What was the version of laravel you had before?

Comment: When I first installed it, it was 5.1.4, then it got upgraded to 5.1.5 and then to 5.1.6. But it was working forawhile after the upgrade. I think the last command I did was `composer dumpautoload` which was a few hours after the upgrade and shortly after that I started noticing these errors. Not sure if dumpautoload can cause this error so if the last upgrade caused it.

Comment: Is you "bootstrap/cache" directory writeable?

Comment: your app is calling view method on Response class, but response class has no view method, so find the file where it is calling this method & remove it & replace it with correct method

Comment: @NehalHasnayeen You are spot-on! No idea how you guessed it. I had this in my route added `App::missing(function($exception) {    return view('index');});` that was causing this error. Once I removed that, everything worked both in browser as well as the composer commands. I didn't see that error straight after adding it probably due to caching which made me think its probably the update since it all happened around the same time. Searching the net took me in the wrong direction. You hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Now it takes me to my final question - why is the catch-all route not working? I have added my full route file in my OP. Lastly, I will be much obliged if you can add the above as the answer so I can accept it. Thank you so much. You have helped me tremendously! :)

Comment: sorry didn't understand your last question. none of your route not working, thats what  you meant?

Comment: no.. all the routes are working fine except for the last one. I mean the first one that goes to index and the next one for `api/authenticate` works fine. But when I add the last catch-all route `App::missing...`, then it throws the error and none of them are accessible. If I remove the last catch-all route, everything else works.

Comment: App::missing is for laravel 4 version, it is removed in laravel 5 , for custom exception handling there is a handler class in app\exceptions folder. use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1st error:
your app is calling view method on Response class, but response class has no view method, so find the file where it is calling this method & remove it & replace it with correct method

For 2nd error:
App::missing is for laravel 4 version, it is removed in laravel 5. To achieve the same in your app\exceptions\handler.php file add this in render method

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
        return response()->view('index', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```